# How to create a Dataframe from multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a little issue with my the data I have (multiple dictionaries) to process and create a Dataframe from them.

This what the data look like:

```
print(data)
0         {'john': True}
1         {'joe': True}
2         {'tom': True}
3         {'mark': False}
4         {'andrew': True}
                       ...                  
93        {'david': False}
94        {'luke': False}
95        {'vincent': True}
96        {'oliver': True}
97        {'matthew': True}
Length: 98, dtype: object
```

Basically what I want is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = data[0].keys()
df['result'] = data[0].values()
print(df)

    name    result
0   john    True
```

So 1 dataframe with 2 columns - name and result.

How can I apply that procedure for all dictionaries in `data` and have 1 output in the same Dataframe?
I was not able to replicate that action via lambda function, but maybe I was not doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(data.apply(lambda x: list(x.items())[0]).values.tolist())
```

you can rename columns, using:

```
df.rename(columns={0: 'name', 1: 'result'}, inplace=True)
```

what do you want? a `dataframe` with 2 `column`s, so we can find an idea...
we konw that `pd.DataFrame` is a constructor that get `data` and convert it to `dataframe` and **if `data` be in 2d form like a 2d list or 2d numpy array or something else** will been converted to a `dataframe` with 2 columns.

ok, now, we have idea... so, let's start.... and convert data to 2d form

Hmm.. oh... every cell in `data series` is a `dictionary` and python provide a builtin method to convert it to 2d form: `items`:

```
data.apply(lambda x: x.items())
```

output:

```
0       ((john, True))
1        ((joe, True))
2        ((tom, True))
3      ((mark, False))
...
```

wow, it's good... but, wait... we just need `(john, True)`, and a parentheses is useless and `items` add it for `dictionary` with more than one `key-value` like: `{'john': True, 'jane': False, 'joe': True}`...

but, there, we only have one, and must remove it... I mean just select first element of this: `((john, True))`...
unfortunately... items output doesn't allow us to select first element,so, we convert it to `list` and then select first element:

```
data.apply(lambda x: list(x.items())[0])
```

output:

```
0       (john, True)
1        (joe, True)
2        (tom, True)
```

oh.. it's 1d in every cell, and 2d in total (series, itself, is a dimension)

if you give a series to `pd.DataFrame` nothing was changed... and it give you that, again... so, you must change it to a `list`...

`pandas` has a builtin property: `values` that give you what make that `dataframe` or `series` as a `numpy array` and you can give it to someone else and he\she make `dataframe` from that again...

did you notice? **again** so, you must convert it to `2d list`. this `array`,itself, is 2d, so just convert it to `list`: `.tolist()`:

```
data.apply(lambda x: list(x.items())[0]).values.tolist()
```

output:

```
[('john', True),
 ('joe', True),
 ('tom', True),
 ('mark', False),
 ('andrew', True),
...]
```

oh... a beautiful, clean and 2d list... pass it to `pd.DataFrame`... :))

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MoRe, it's working.

Nevertheless, I was going through each action in the code to understand directly what needed to be done prior the result:
1. the lambda function will output a panda series with such lines:
`0     (0, {'pfalzwerke netz ag': True})`

2. then you extracted values and put them in a list with this part of code:
`.values.tolist()`

3. the list is sent into the dataframe constructor

Unfortunately, I'm not 100% comprehending the full code, can you please give me a hint how the steps flow was going? 

Thank you in advance

Comment: @straight_edge I edit my post, just now... hope be helpfull

Comment: this is great, I now understand completely what was the logic behind. Thank you again

Comment: @straight_edge Tnx, if you want to thanks me, just say **peace be upon muhammad and his holy family** :)) even if you don't believe in Isalm... If you did that, upvote my comment... if not, then it is ok because it isn't required :))